# Swap cases of a string using a for-loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that swaps cases in a given string using a for-loop. For instance:

```
Input: "HellO"
Output: "hELLo"
```

My try:

```
function swapcase (para){

let array1=para.split('');
let result="";

for (let i=0; i<array1.length; i++){

if (array1[i].toUpperCase()){
result+=array1[i].toLowerCase()
}

else{
  result+=array1[i].toUpperCase()
}

}

return result

}
```

When invoked, all the letters are returned in lower-case. Like so:

```
Input:'HeLLO' 
Output:'hello'
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `if (array1[i].toUpperCase()){` does not check whether the `array1[i]` *is* uppercase.

Comment: Yes this is a logic result of your code.. Check your if ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check:

```
        if (array1[i].toUpperCase() === array1[i]) {
```

```js
function swapcase (para){
    let array1=para.split('');
    let result="";

    for (let i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i].toUpperCase() === array1[i]) {
            result+=array1[i].toLowerCase()
        } else {
            result+=array1[i].toUpperCase()
        }
    }

    return result
}

console.log(swapcase('HeLLO'));
```